# RHEL 6 sa and sar log file size

Tags: rhel, logs, sysstat

I am trying to figure out why sa and sar log files are much larger on one of our servers. Basically double the size

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100M Feb  5 23:59 sa05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100M Feb  6 23:59 sa06
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100M Feb  7 23:59 sa07

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 141M Feb  5 23:53 sar05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 141M Feb  6 23:53 sar06
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 141M Feb  7 23:53 sar07
```

compare to another server

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34M Feb  5 23:59 sa05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34M Feb  6 23:59 sa06
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34M Feb  7 23:59 sa07

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57M Feb  5 23:53 sar05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57M Feb  6 23:53 sar06
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57M Feb  7 23:53 sar07
```

Anyone sees this before and any idea to reduce sa/sar log size?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the command line arguments that collect sar data are the same on the 2 systems?  Do you have more cores or devices on the larger-file system?  Or perhaps it's just busier?

Each line has to print stats, and the bigger the numbers, or the more devices to log (e.g: adding ethernet interfaces has a multiplicative impact on network stats like sar -n DEV, interrupts, etc)  the bigger the file is, as it all adds up.

Also perhaps you can compress prior day logs?